# How to debug this NodeJS error: TypeError: Cannot read property '_writableState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, promise, async-await

I am trying to write a NodeJS application and running into an error.  I can't tell why it is happening.  It seems completely unrelated to the part of the code where it is happening.

None of the files referenced in the error messages belong to my project.

#### The Code

In this block of code, I have a breakpoint on every line, and it runs until the `if` statement.  After that, it prints the error message and crashes.

Adding any number of `console.log("text")` statements after `this.events.send` doesn't really change anything.  The code still runs until the `if` statement and then crashes.

```js
this.events.send('request', {requestIndex: i});

// wait if there is a delay for the request
if (request.ms_delay && request.ms_delay > 0) { // execution stops after this line
    await (() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, request.ms_delay);
        });
    })();
}

let outcome = await this.protocol.sendRequest(request);
```

In the previous block of code, the first line publishes an event.  As a result, this code is run. Since the error mentions streams and this is the only thing that uses streams in that code, the error should be somewhere here.  The socket referenced here is a sock.io socket.

```js
protected sendMessage(message: MessageWrapper) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (this.socket && this.socket.connected) {
            try {
                if (message.channel) {
                    this.socket.emit(message.channel, message.body);
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    this.socket.send(message.body);
                    resolve();
                }
            } catch {
                reject();
            }
        } else {
            reject();
        }
    });
}
```

The client does in fact receive the message sent through the socket.

#### The Error Message

```
_stream_writable.js:570
  const state = this._writableState;
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '_writableState' of undefined
    at Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:570:22)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:483:3)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:474:7)
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:92:10)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Any insight into what might be causing this problem or how to investigate the error would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: The error is not happening in that bit of code. So it will help if you share any writeable stream that you may be using. This could be a file you're writing to, a request you're sending...

Comment: *"it runs until the if statement"* ... so, I take it you've determined that `this.events.send('request', {requestIndex: i});` causes the issue? because it's not the comment, right

Comment: What is `this.events`?

Comment: @Jacob It is a pretty generic pub/sub implementation.

Comment: If it's the call to `this.events.send` that's failing, we'll need to see the code of that method, or if it's an object that is not in your code, we need to know what type of object it is specifically. We have no idea if you're calling that function correctly or if the function you're calling contains an error.

Comment: @Jacob the call to this.events.send returns without any errors.  It is code I wrote myself, and I am sure it works and I am calling it correctly.  I suspect the issue is in a promise created in a callback for the `request` event.  The second code listing shows the only promise created during a callback subscribed to that event that makes use of streams.

Comment: This is the point where you should be creating a [mcve], because that's the exercise that lets you (a) almost always discover what's wrong entirely on your own, but also (b) produce code that you can drop into a question that people can literally copy-paste and run to see the exact same error for themselves.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am working on it, but It is proving to be quite hard.  I don't understand what the problem is well enough to reproduce it.  Everything looks fine to me, and then it crashes.  When I add more code between `this.events.send` and the `if` statement, it still crashes at the `if` statement.

Comment: Btw, your `sendMessage` function should not return a promise, it does nothing asynchronous. And those `try` blocks are superfluous as well, the promise constructor already catches any synchronous exceptions in the executor.

Comment: To me this looks like a case of passing a function reference that's not bound to a context, hence "Cannot read property '_writableState' of undefined." Seems like something is calling a writable stream's method such that `this` is undefined or something like that.

Comment: @Jacob You are right, the error message does look like that.  My code does not contain the string `_writableState` anywhere.  Do you think this could be a bug in either node or socket.io?  Maybe typescript generated some code with that string?  It doesn't come up in a search though, so I doubt it's typescript.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a bug in where you're setting up your socket.io instance? Wouldn't hurt to post that. The call causing the error is probably in socket.io, but that doesn't rule out your code using it incorrectly.

Comment: Well, the last line is actually being called despite the breakpoint not being hit.  That function sends a TCP message (also using a stream).  It still doesn't look like anything should be going wrong.  Looks like I have some more digging to do.